# How to differentiate identical divs for use in a DOM function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ejs

I have a set of "cards" on my front end with a front side and a back side, these cards are created from a forEach script meaning there is a potentially different quantity each time and look something like this.

```
<div class="card-container" onclick="flip()">
                    <div class="card">   
                        <div class="front">
                                <p> front of card </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                                <p> back of card</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

As you may have noticed, there is a flip() function, this displays the back of the card and hides the front and vice versa when clicked a second time. I would like this function only to apply to the *current* card, that is, the one that the user clicks, at the moment when I click it it turns over *all* of the cards.

```
function flip() {
    $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

My first solution was to try to increment the class names (card1, card2 etc.) and copy the function for each different class name, however the following example syntax gave me the error that the document object could not be found, which presumably relates to the fact I am using ejs.

```
var card = document.createElement('div');
card.classList.add('card');
```

I am hoping that there is a solution in jQuery that allows you to specify that the function only be carried out on 1 div, or on children of the selected div as this would be the neatest solution I think.

Otherwise I think I need to work out a way to increment the div names through ejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with jquery click event handler. find card from the clicked div instead of flipping all cards.

Remove onclick function from html

```
<div class="card-container">
                    <div class="card">   
                        <div class="front">
                                <p> front of card </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                                <p> back of card</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Use below jquery

```
$(function(){
  $('.card-container').on("click", function(){
     $(this).find('.card').toggleClass("flipped");
  });
});
```

Comment: See my comment to the question

Comment: yeah, i just saw your comment after posting my answer. User can follow the same

Comment: happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

If the cards exist at load time do this

```
$('.card-container').on("click",function() { $(this).find(".card").toggleClass('flipped'); });
```

or

```
$('.card').on("click",function() { $(this).toggleClass('flipped'); });
```

If NOT then you need to delegate:

```
$(document).on("click",".card", function() { $(this).toggleClass('flipped'); });
```

`$(document)` can be changed to any static parent container

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `this` in from your `onclick` function, it's relatively easy to use it in your flip function:

```js
function flip(element) {
  $(element).toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

```css
.card-container {
  background-color: rgba(255, 245, 250, 0.9);
  border-top: solid 10px rgb(50, 200, 100);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px 1px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.flipped {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 6px 3px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.2);
  top: -5px;
}

body {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-container" onclick="flip(this)">
        <div class="card">   
            <div class="front">
                    <p> front of card </p>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                    <p> back of card</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="card-container" onclick="flip(this)">
        <div class="card">   
            <div class="front">
                    <p> front of card </p>
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                    <p> back of card</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I added some styling just to illustrate when the cards get the `flipped` class.

Comment: excuse my ignorance but what is e? 
`function flip(e) {
  $(e).toggleClass('flipped');
}`

Comment: No need to apologise; `e`, in this context, is `this`, because that's what you passed in using the `onclick`. The `this`, in this context, is the dom element which was clicked.

Comment: Poor choice of variable name since (e) is normally the event - also passing this and then have to jQuery it is not good practice. Using unobtrusive event handling is better.

Comment: ... or the element? I've seen e used for both used regularly. Using single letters for variable naming is _never_ good practice, really. If this was proper code that wasn't for some random stack overflow answer I'd have put in more effort. I'll update the answer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can only target the selected div by modifying the flip function to

```
function flip(e) {
    $(e.target).toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

Comment: This would only work if you also pass in `this` using the `onclick` attribute

Comment: The event object is passed whether you pass it or not I believe. So passing the this or not in click attribute is same

Comment: I'm fairly sure it isn't; I wrote code to test it, and unless you pass this, nothing is passed. Perhaps you could include a snippet to show this working without `this` being passed via the `onclick`?